# What exactly is a 'Damage roll' for Grim Servant O' Death/No Mercy edges?

Tags: damage, savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

Let's say your gun does 2d6 damage. If you have any **Grim Servant** edges, would that mean you would be shooting at a 2d6+1, or is it a 1d6+1 and 1d6+1?

Both **Grim Serv'** and **No Mercy** use the term *'damage roll'*, but does that mean each die rolled or the entire roll?

The meaning either makes **Grim** Stronger and **Mercy** weaker (*'damage roll'* counts as a single die meaning you only get to re-roll one die for **Mercy**, but get a plus one to all dice rolled for **Grim**) or vice-versa (**Grim** adds only a single +1 no matter the amount of dice, but **Mercy** gets to re-roll each die they had rolled).

Answer (score 5):

'Damage' and 'damage roll' are interchangeable in this sense in SW. The books never refer to individual dice rolled for damage, except when adding them to damage. Even modifiers that seem to be added to individual dice are added to the total. A trait roll with d12+1 in the trait is rolled as d12/d6(wild)+1 and you get the +1 even if you use the wild die for the result.

Thus 2d6 damage with a +1 modifier is 2d6+1.

Comment: 'A trait roll with d12+1 is rolled at d12+d6+1' is unclear, as you could interpret that as adding the d12 and d6 together to get a result. What you actually do in those circumstances is roll both, and add 1 to whichever is higher.

Comment: @Wibbs Is it clearer with a "/"? I am just assuming a basic familiarity with SW rules...

Comment: A little. The concern I have is that one of the things new players often confuse is the difference between adding dice for damage rolls and taking the highest for trait rolls. IMO it would be a much clearer answer if you explicitly spelled that out. I don't think assuming basic familiarity with the rules is necessarily a good idea here.

Comment: @Wibbs I wouldn't even bring up trait rolls, but this is the closest example I found that can shed a bit of light on +number vs +dX. The SW rules are notoriously unquotable on basic rules (at least the Deluxe edition that I have). I do not want to write a whole tutorial to SW rolling here.

Comment: Assuming basic familiarity is part of the stack exchange model: there's nothing wrong in doing that.

Comment: @Hemlock You are welcome. If you are satisfied with an answer, you can show it by accepting it (click the tick below the voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

> Both Grim Serv' and No Mercy use the term 'damage roll' but does that mean each dice rolled or the entire roll?

### It means the entire roll.

To quote the rule book (Chapter 3: Combat)

> **Damage**
>
> After a successful close combat or ranged hit, the attacker rolls damage. Ranged weapons do fixed damage as listed in the Gear section. Most pistols, for example, cause 2d6 damage.
>
> Hand weapons cause damage equal to the attacker’s Strength die plus a second die, which depends on the weapon. A barbarian with a d12 Strength and a long sword (d8 damage) rolls d12+d8 damage. Even though Strength is used to determine melee damage, this isn’t a Trait roll. Wild Cards don’t add a Wild Die to the roll and they can’t spend Bennies if they’re unhappy with the results.
>
> **All damage rolls can Ace.**
> ►►Unarmed Combat Damage: An unarmed combatant rolls only his Strength die.
> ►►Bonus Damage: Well-placed attacks are more likely to hit vital areas, and so do more damage. If your hero gets a raise on his attack roll (regardless of how many raises), he adds +1d6 to the final total. This roll may also Ace!

And then we go to the extended combat example at the end of the chapter for further clarity.

> **Private Dan’– Joker**
>
> Dan whips out a grenade and places the Medium Burst Template directly over three of the zombies. They’re in Short Range so there are no penalties to the roll. The Joker gives him a +2 and his Throwing is d6. He rolls a 6, which is an Ace. He rolls again and gets a 4. That’s 6+4+2 for the Joker, or 12. He hits with a raise over the standard TN of 4. Grenades cause 3d6 damage, and 4d6 with the raise. After Acing and adding all the dice together, he gets a 23. That’s far more than a raise over the zombies’ Toughness 7, so that’s a wound to each. They’re Extras so that’s all they can take and all three are wiped out.

Remember the tag line: Fast, Furious, Fun! Adding +1 to each die is not fast, and being on the other end of that kind of damage isn't fun either. If you can read a rule one of two ways, one way is slow and the other way is faster, the faster method is usually the correct interpretation.

Finally, you can get official answers from Pinnacle [on their forums](https://www.pegforum.com/).